# Not able to export datatable having 150+ columns to PDF using itextsharp

Tags: c#, winforms, export-to-pdf

I am using  itextsharp.dll for exporting my datatable from windows form to pdf.
I was able to export if there is only 10 columns but when i select all(157) the columns it exports the pdf i.e file is getting created but in that file no data is getting written. I am using PdfPTable which is creating a problem.
Can someone please help in resolving the issue.??
Thanks in advance.

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(dtToBeExported.Columns.Count);

            //Table Header
            for (int i = 0; i < dtToBeExported.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(dtToBeExported.Columns[i].ColumnName));
                cell.BackgroundColor = BaseColor.GRAY;
                cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
                cell.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
                table.AddCell(cell);
            }
            //Table Data
            for (int i = 0; i < dtToBeExported.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < dtToBeExported.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(Convert.ToString(dtToBeExported.Rows[i][j])));
                    cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
                    cell.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
                    table.AddCell(cell);
                }
            }
            document.Add(table);
```

Comment: Show us your code

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: My txt file has 150+ columns i am converting my file to data table and then i am exporting that data table to pdf.But when number of columns are less i.e 10 or 11 file gets exported with data but when i select all the columns file gets exported successfully but with no data.